# Need to clear MySQL InnoDB lock without restarting database

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

I have an MySQL InnoDB lock that is preventing a user from logging in. I don't care about the cause of this lock at the moment - I just need to clear the lock without restarting the database. Killing the query process does nothing FYI. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem with MyIsam and i was able to solve it by repairing the table. I dont know it that would help, but it's a start

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately REPAIR TABLE isn't used with InnoDB.

Comment: Use CHECK TABLE and tell us what the output is.

Comment: CHECK TABLE returns status of OK.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is how I wound up solving the problem:

```
mysql> show engine innodb status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Type: InnoDB
  Name: 
Status: 
=====================================
120710 18:05:37 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 37 seconds
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 208374, signal count 196902
Mutex spin waits 0, rounds 39211638, OS waits 80663
RW-shared spins 588505, OS waits 68505; RW-excl spins 3204502, OS waits 53586
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 1 3626791829
Purge done for trx's n:o < 1 3625948819 undo n:o < 0 0
History list length 6754
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
...
---TRANSACTION 1 3625948818, ACTIVE 2892 sec, process no 1981, OS thread id 140020625811200
2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1

>>>>> MySQL thread id 14982, query id 232584561 localhost dbuser

Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 1 3625948819, sees < 1 3625948817

mysql> kill 14982;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Note that the line with the >>>>> is where the MySQL thread ID is defined - it is this thread that should be killed.

Please see [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/09/18/how-to-debug-innodb-lock-waits/) post as well - very useful.

Comment: you will want to use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` with MySQL 5.5 and above (the `ENGINE` used to be optional)